# Ruby movement across matrix

Tags: ruby, matrix

I'm trying to validate one vector of 8 positions. This positions are movements in a matrix of NxM where N = columns and M = rows.

The movements are:

- North -> 0
- South -> 1
- East -> 2
- West -> 3

The main objective is that the hole movement solution wouln't be out of bounds of the matrix.

Here is my code:

Iterate until a valid solution is found.

```
while ! valid                                                                         
  start_solution = generate_random_solution
  valid = validate_solution(start_solution)
end
```

I don't have any problem generating random vectors with the movment numbers. That is the function of the generate_random_solution.

```
def validate_solution(solution)
  position = @start.dup
  move_count = 0
  solution.each do |movement|
    next_position = move(movement, position)
    unless next_position.nil?
      position = next_position
      move_count += 1
    end
  end
  move_count == @num_moves ? true : false
end
```

@start in this case is (0,0) the first position of a 3x3 matrix. 
@num_moves is N * N - 1. The number of movements that I can do in the matrix.

Here is the function that returns the new position, if the movement is invalid the default value is nil.

```
def move(mov, pos)
  case mov
    when 0 # NORTH
      return Position.new(pos.x, pos.y - 1) if pos.y > 0
    when 1 # SOUTH
      return Position.new(pos.x, pos.y + 1) if pos.y < @m
    when 2 # EAST
      return Position.new(pos.x + 1, pos.y) if pos.x < @n
    when 3 # WEST
      return Position.new(pos.x - 1, pos.y) if pos.x > 0
  end
end
```

Here is my problem. It seems that in some point the movement function don't return nil and allow that a vector be out of bounds.

http://pastebin.com/CchpyXwz

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do @m and @n get set, and are you sure they are correct?

Comment: Here is the hole class board.rb code. http://pastebin.com/7ihxS7HR You can see that I set this variables with the class constructor. I verified the values and are correct.

Comment: your position co-ordinates start with `0` so they should be limited to `@m - 1` and `@n - 1`

Comment: if you post stacktraces, make sure all the methods named in the callstack are in the post WITH LINE-NUMBERS!